# Failed to run kernel v4.13.11 on ubuntu17.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I followed the tutorial here : [How to build and install the latest Linux kernel from source](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-and-installing-the-latest-linux-kernel-from-source-6d8df5345980)

without modifying the .config file. I used make olddefconfig

the compiling process was successful, however it failed to boot in the new kernel.

[image]

The RAM I assigned to the VM is 2GB, I think it's enough for a linux kernel. There must be something wrong with my new kernel.

And I noticed that the new kernel I built is 475MB, 10x larger than the previous one, but I don't know why.

[image]

**Note**: total RAM is 8GB, total CPU is i5 dual-core with 4 thread.

Comment: Try stripping your modules before installing : `sudo make MODULES_STRIP_INSTALL=1 modules_install` and then `sudo make install`

Comment: Done!But Why is this NOT mentioned in most tutorials? Without this setting the kernel would be too large to boot.

Comment: your scenario might be pretty uncommon, and that's why.

Comment: really……I always encounter this error without it....